# Put a blanket over a div to "disable" all controls within the div

Tags: css, html, transparency

I made a short example of what I have so far [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43MjD/), but the thing I want to be possible is that when you move your mouse over the div, and you click on a point of the div where there is a textbox (in this example), you do not interact with the textbox, you still only interact with the div. Like if there was an invisible blanket over the textbox, and you trigger the click event of the blanket, but do not gain focus on the textbox.

I have searched a bit around and not a lot of people seem to have asked about this, but I found someone saying I could use a transparent image (1x1 px) of the containing div, and make it repeat like so

```
background-image: url('transparent.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
```

But to no avail. It is still possible to "click through" the div. I also tried setting

```
background: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0);
```

and

```
opacity: 0;
```

of the transparent div, and it was still click-through. I have also fiddled with some z-index, and that made no difference either (setting the z-index of the blanket to a higher value than the z-index of the textbox).

Comment: Maybe, it's better to do smth like `.transperent > * {visibility: hidden; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're looking for, something like this will work: http://jsfiddle.net/43MjD/2/ (if you want to see the div over the top, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/43MjD/3/) fiddle)

```
#content{
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#content:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

-

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

For it work work in IE, you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/43MjD/6/

Comment: Works like a charm. Fantastic, thank you. Does the code just insert an empty element "after" the #content that then fills up all the space of the div?

Comment: @LarsJensen yeah, pretty much

Comment: Short comment. I just realized today that this actually does not work in at least IE10, but it works in Opera and Chrome. Is there some fix I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Adding preventDefault() to .transparent will not work.

You can use the solution suggested by @Prisoner however it uses content attribute which is not supported in all browsers. You could use this jQuery solution which deselects the box when its clicked in -

```
jQuery('INPUT').click(function (e) {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Comment: This would work if the textbox is going to have a static positioning, but I am unfortunately going to have it in a (jQueryUI) draggable div, where the field "over" the textbox has to be a draggable anchor aswell. But you couldn't have known that since I forgot to mention it. :-)

Comment: In regards to using the content attribute, you could easily just define another div inside the `#content` and assign `#content:after` to that div, then you can remove the `content: ' ';`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set css z-index to a large value like 10 or 15 to the blanket div and specify position property to either absolute or relative because z-index only work with positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
transparent = $(".transparent")
transparent.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // code to be executed when clicked
});
```

The `event.preventDefault()` prevents the textbox from being selected.

Comment: It still puts the caret in the textbox as if the blanket did not exist, unfortunately.